# Responsive CSS doesn't work on smartphone

Tags: html, css, asp.net

i'm writing an asp.net responsive page.

i'm using this CSS structure:

```
.customNavbar {
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navMenu {
    display: none;
}

 .divTopTicket {
    display: none;
}

    /**** OTHER THINGS FOR DESKTOP LAYOUT *****/


@media (max-width: 600px) {

    /**** LAYOUT FOR SMALLER SCREEN *****/

}
```

Actually i've this situation:

I open the page with a browser on my desktop and i get the right desktop layout. Then i try to reduce the dimension of the browser's window manually and at 600px i get the right responsive layout.

After this i've tryed to open the page with a smartphone and i've this problem:

The page opens like a desktop browser with the normal layout and i really do not understand why. I think the CSS is right.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Have you set this tag in the header - <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: just an advice, you should try `@media only screen and (min-width : <device width>)` for a mobile-first web app/page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the viewport tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Otherwise your phone is going to treat the website as if it's a desktop site.

For example, in your head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this meta tag as well, and don't forget to use @media only screen and (min-width : ) inside your CSS file.
: 767px is the perfect width for tablets and mobile devices.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```